# Dynamic content in ExtJS Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

**TLDR** I want to add some dynamic content into an Ext-JS window / popup.

---

Currently I have tried assigning this content to a div and pulling on the innerhtml of that div like:

```
                new Ext.Window({
                height: 50,
                width: 160,
                x: 0,
                y: 30,
                layout: "fit",
                html: document.getElementById('output').innerHTML;
            }).show();
```

Am using jquery & getjson to get the dynamic data.

But  that does nothing at all. 
Has anyone done something similar before?

Can I give the html of the window an id and use it like an element?

Comment: My Answer below works above does not. It simply breaks the window completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code should have worked fine. "Breaks completely" isn't really very useful for describing the problem.

However if you're trying to load complicated markup into a window, using the contentEl approach is probably better.

Note that the layout: 'fit' in the window is redundant, because you have no child items.

Comment: No child items in my example anyway :P. It does not allow me to place the javascript statement above in the example. It crashes and burns without much error.

Answer (score 1):

You can register the content of a div into the window or any other panel etc using the contentEl method.

```
contentEl: 'ElementID'
```

Example:

```
                new Ext.Window({
                    title: 'Measurement',
                    height: 50,
                    width: 160,
                    resizable: false,
                    closeAction: "hide",
                    x: 0,
                    y: 30,
                    layout: "fit",
                    contentEl: 'output'
                }).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get more verbose error information use the debug version of Ext.js.

Your example should work, unless 
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML does not exist when you are trying to show your window, (which you are doing immediately on creation).